# Find the minimum of the function $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1 + x_2 + 3)^2 + (3x_1 + x_2 - 1)^2 + (2x_1 + x_2 + 1)^2$

Tags: linear-algebra

Find the minimum of the function $f(x_1,x_2) = (x_1 + x_2 + 3)^2 + (3x_1 + x_2 - 1)^2 + (2x_1 + x_2 + 1)^2$.

We've been instructed to solve this by writing $f(x_1,x_2)$ as $||Ax - b||^2$, and $x = [x_1,x_2]^T$.

I'm not quite sure how to solve this, this is $Ax - b$ in my opinion:

$
        \begin{pmatrix}
        1 & 1  \\
        3 & 1  \\
        2 & 1 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$
$(x_1,x_2)
^T -  (-3,-1,1)$

How do I continue from here?

Comment: Hint - expand it out and try writing as a quadratic form with 2x2 matrix $A$.

Comment: @Macavity You mean $Ax = b$? but what about the "$^2$"?

Comment: You need to express that quadratic in the form $||Ax-b||^2= x^TA^TAx-2b^TAx+b^Tb$. Not knowing exactly what course (are you doing QP?) and how it is being taught, I would hesitate to do this in my own way. If you have been given that hint, I am sure you have more instructions/ context.

Comment: Oh I see, and did I write $A$, $b$ correctly? and after I solve $||Ax - b||^2$ should I get $x_1 = 2, x_2 = -5$? and another question, how do I solve it? do I need to make it equal to zero?

Comment: @Macavity What should be my $A$ then?

Comment: The equation should be $$\begin{bmatrix}1&1\\3&1\\2&1\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x_1\\x_2\end{bmatrix} -\begin{bmatrix}-3\\1\\-1\end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: @robjohn Yup it works. and if I want the minimum I need to solve the nornmalized system of it.

Comment: Yes. This is just what Christian Blatter's answer says.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are told to minimize $\|Ax-b\|^2$ for
$$[A]:=\left[\matrix{1&1\cr 3&1\cr 2&1\cr}\right],\qquad b=(-3,1,-1)^\top\ .$$Now
$$A:\quad {\mathbb R}^2\to{\mathbb R}^3,\qquad x\mapsto Ax$$
is the parametric representation of a $2$-plane $\pi$  in ${\mathbb R}^3$. This plane is spanned by the column vectors $a_1=(1,3,2)^\top$ and $a_2=(1,1,1)^\top$ of $[A]$, and its normal  computes to $$n=a_1\times a_2=(1,1,-2)^\top\ .$$ The point in $p\in \pi$ nearest to $b$ is characterized by the condition $b-p\perp \pi$, or $b-p=\lambda n$ for some $\lambda\in {\mathbb R}$. Since $p=Ax=x_1a_1+x_2 a_2$ for some unknown $x_1$, $x_2$ we now have to solve the $3\times3$ linear system 
$$x_1 a_1+x_2 a_2 +\lambda n= b$$
for $x_1$, $x_2$ (and $\lambda)$. The computation gives $x_1=2$, $x_2=-5$ (and $\lambda=0$, by accident). For this $x$ we have $$f(x)=\|Ax-b\|^2=\|p-b\|^2=\|\lambda n\|^2=0\ .$$

Comment: Thank you! Btw, why $b = (-3,1,-1)$ and not $(3,-1,1)$?

Comment: Check with the definition of $f$ in the title. Note that we are dealing with $Ax-b$, not with $Ax+b$.

Comment: Do you have any idea why $A^TAx = A^Tb$ won't yield the same solution $x_1 = 2, x_2 = -5$?

Comment: I gave a solution along geometric lines, given the hint. Of course there is also the book solution in terms of general linear regression theory.

Comment: Actually it does work, my mistake. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Some alternative solution, which I think it's a lot easier.

Notice that we add non - negative terms. This means that $f(x_1,x_2)\ge 0 ,\forall x_1,x_2 \in \mathbb R.$

Solving the system :

$$\left.\begin{array}{l}
x_1+x_2+3= 0\\
3x_1+x_2 - 1 =0
\end{array}
\right\}\implies x_1=2, x_2 = -5
$$

We also observe that for these values the third parenthesis becomes $2x_1+x_2+1=2\cdot 2-5+1=0$

Thus, for $(x_1,x_2) = (2,-5)$ we have that $f$ attains its minimum value, which is zero.

---

Taking for granted that the minimum value of $f$ is zero, then writing $f$ in the suggested form implies that $ \|Ax-b\|^2 = 0\iff Ax - b = 0 \iff Ax = b$. So, it sufficient to solve the system $Ax = b$.

Comment: I suspect the problem is to illustrate a more general approach,  so method is important here.

Comment: @Macavity Do you think you can show how to approach it with the hint I was instructed with?

Comment: @TheNassisdr do you know how to solve it with the hint I was instructed with?

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS Taking for granted that the minimum value of $f$ is zero, then writing $f$ in the suggested form implies that $ \|Ax-b\|^2 = 0\iff Ax - b = 0 \iff Ax = b$. So, it sufficient to solve the system $Ax = b$.

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS By the way, $b = [-3,1,-1]^T$.

Comment: @thanasissdr but $Ax = b$ won't yield a solution, do I need to solve $A^TAx = A^Tb$ then?

Comment: @thanasissdr If yes, it will yield a solution $-1,3$

Comment: @thanasissdr Actually it does work, my mistake. thanks!

Comment: @IlanAizelmanWS You are welcome!

Answer (score 2):

I would find the critical point(s), then see what information the Hessian matrix provides.

\begin{equation}
\partial_{x_1} f = 7x_1 + 3x_2 + 1 = 0,
\end{equation}
and 
\begin{equation}
\partial_{x_2} f = 2x_1 + x_2 + 1 = 0,
\end{equation}
Solve this system to find that the critical point is at $(2,-5).$

The Hessian is 
\begin{equation}
H = \begin{pmatrix}
\partial_{x_1 x_1} f & \partial_{x_1 x_2} f\\ \partial_{x_2 x_1} f & \partial_{x_2 x_2} f
\end{pmatrix} =
\begin{pmatrix}
38 & 12 \\ 12  & 6 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
Since all leading minors are positive, we know that the critical point must be a minimum.  Thus, the minimum of the function is $m = f(2,-5).$

Answer (score 2):

$$
\begin{align}
&\nabla\left[(x_1+x_2+3)^2+(3x_1+x_2-1)^2+(2x_1+x_2+1)^2\right]\\
&=2(x_1+x_2+3)\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
+2(3x_1+x_2-1)\begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix}
+2(2x_1+x_2+1)\begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}\\
&=\begin{bmatrix}28x_1+12x_2+4\\12x_1+6x_2+6\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}
$$
This vanishes when $x_1=2$ and $x_2=-5$. Plugging this point into the function gives
$$
0^2+0^2+0^2=0
$$
Knowing this, we can write
$$
\begin{align}
&(x_1+x_2+3)^2+(3x_1+x_2-1)^2+(2x_1+x_2+1)^2\\
&=((x_1-2)+(x_2+5))^2+(3(x_1-2)+(x_2+5))^2+(2(x_1-2)+(x_2+5))^2\\
&=14(x_1-2)^2+12(x_1-2)(x_2+5)+3(x_2+5)^2\\
&=2(x_1-2)^2+3(2(x_1-2)+(x_2+5))^2\\
\end{align}
$$